# Returning local static in C

Tags: c, variables, static, return, return-value

In C language, scope of the `static` variable through out the file. 
In the following code, function returns the static variable.

```
int fun(){
    static int i = 10;
    return i;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", fun());
    return 0;
}
```

And printed output 10.

So, Is returning **local static** in C undefined behaviour or well-defined?

Comment: well-defined. In this case it is not necessary to be `static`. Its same as `return 10;`

Comment: perfectly well defined..

Comment: Maybe I rushed my answer, just to clarify, is there anything in specific that makes you think this would be UB?

Comment: I believe you are confusing this with `int* fun (void) { static int i = 10; return &i; }` versus `int* fun (void) { int i = 10; return &i; }`, which is another story. The former is well-defined, the latter is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 8):

You seem to have missed the whole *logic* for a `return` statement.

In this snippet, you are actually returning the *value* (of the variable), so, without the `static` storage also, the code is fine.

In case, you want to return the *address* of a variable, it needs to outlast the scope of the function. In that case, you need to have a variable with `static` storage, so that the returned address is valid (so that it can be used meaningfully from the caller function) even outside the function in which it is defined. So, either

- you use a pointer returned by allocator functions, like `malloc()` or family
- use the address of a variable defined with `static` storage class.